# Jquery - adding parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and i have a problem.

I have script that for resize each image in some div. And i want to insert that image into non existing div (create div-parent), how?

EDIT:

I've got this code:

```
$('#content img').each(function() {

            if( $(this).width() > maxWidth || $(this).height() > maxHeight )
            {   
                var ratio = 0;
                if( $(this).width() > $(this).height() )
                {
                    ratio = maxWidth / $(this).width();
                    $(this).css('width', maxWidth + 'px');
                    $(this).css('height', ( $(this).height() * ratio) + 'px' );
                }
                else
                {
                    ratio = maxHeight / $(this).height();
                    $(this).css('width', ($(this).width() * ratio) + 'px');
                    $(this).css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
                }

                $(this).addClass('scaled-img');
                $(this).wrap('<div class="test"></div>'); // trying to add

            }                               

            });
});
```

Result:

```
<img src="path.."/>
```

Result that i want:

```
<div><img src="path"/></div>
```

Comment: What does your current jQuery look like? And you html mark-up? Any chance of a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Thanks for JS fiddle website link! Awesome!

Comment: BTW, stop wrapping `$(this)` everywhere. That's wildly inefficient code. Grab a single reference to the value returned by `$(this)` and save it as a local variable so you can reuse it: `var $this = $(this); ... if ($this.width() ...) ...`. Likewise, save the computed width and height, there's no reason to keep computing them.

Comment: The code you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wkBzG/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap).

#### HTML

```
<div id="some-div">
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#some-div > img').wrap('<div class="new-parent"></div>');
});
```

#### Result

```
<div id="some-div">
    <div class="new-parent"><img ... /></div>
    <div class="new-parent"><img ... /></div>
    <div class="new-parent"><img ... /></div>
</div>
```

---

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/aD8yT/) (now with extra kittens!)***

Comment: +1 for the ***extra kittens!*** :) ...and the whole 'useful answer' thing, I guess... :/

Comment: This answer is very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Look at the ".wrap()" jQuery method.  It lets you wrap en element in some other container element:

```
$('#myImage').wrap('<div></div>');
```

If you need to give the container some properties:

```
$('#myImage').wrap($('<div></div>', {
  id: "newWrapper",
  class: 'wrapper banana',
  css: { 'borderColor': 'green', 'borderWidth': '2px' }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the specifics of your script, and marm-up, it's difficult to answer this question properly. But, for general information: to add an image to a div, you can use either [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) or [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

```
$('img').appendTo('#elementToAddImageTo');
```

You could also use:

```
$('#elementToAddImageTo').append($('img'));
```

If you simply want to wrap the `img` elements with a `div` then use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('img').wrap('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#demowrap').wrap('<div id="parent"></div>');
```

where demowrap is the id on the img (u can change this to whatever selects your image.
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

I can't for the life of me figure out why these solutions are not working for me:

```
//everything is an array of 14 items
//footer is in my html andi've tested manually adding the <div class="dot></div> and it works

everything.forEach(function(){

  d = document.createElement('div');
  //this console log proves that it is being created 14 times
  console.log(d)

  $(d).addClass("dot").appendTo($('.footer'))

  //or this: $('.footer').append(d);

})
```

Comment: Ah! for all future readers - my problem was that I was calling the javascript in the header, before the html was created, so my javascript was not aware of the parent element I was trying to append it to